# What is the fastest way to copy entities from one Ignite cache to another?

Tags: java, ignite

I'm looking for a way to copy all entities with given keys from one Ignite cache to another. Whereas one is continuously getting new data, every x seconds all data have to be duplicated to cache2. I have tried to use EntryProcessor because I only need to copy data in place (on same nodes):

```
EntryProcessor p = new EntryProcessor() {
    @Override
    public Object process(MutableEntry entry, Object... objects) throws EntryProcessorException {
        entry.setValue(cache.get((long)entry.getKey()));
        return null;
    }
};

read_cache.invokeAll(key_set, p);
key_set.clear();
```

But It works very slow. Whereas I load data ~ 17k/sec, they are being copied with speed of about 5k/s.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using DataStreamer inside a scan query and/or continuous query. Just don't forget to flush it periodically.